# OpenCV imshow fix region of interest

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I'm building a mini application on top of imshow. The application includes dragging the mouse when you hold down the left mouse button. Unfortunately when zoomed into the image dragging when holding the mouse down already exists within imshow. It moves the ROI of in the zoomed-in image. I have attached an image to make this more clear.
I would like to block this native imshow functionality as it seems to only exist on Ubuntu anyways. But I couldn't find any Flag or reference how to do it.

[image: ROI Example]

Comment: It depends on the graphics library that OpenCV use. If you build OpenCV with GTK+ you should have a simpler GUI with only the image.

Comment: I think the GUI is not really the problem as you can do ``` cv2.namedWindo(name, cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL )``` which gives you a reduced GUI but the the same functionality is still there. Furthermore I actually like the 'zoom in' feature but the dragging feature is interfering with my application

Comment: yeah, but the implementation changes if you build OpenCV with GTK+ or Qt (that you're using now). With GTK+ the implementation is simpler and does not have the same functionalities as with Qt. But, to answer your question, no, there is no way to remove this feature programmatically. Imshow is intended to be used only for debugging purposes, if you want different features you should implement your own method.